# Need to checkout tag/release/branch directories manually during partial checkout

Tags: svn, directory, release, partial

I have an archive which is clobbered with undesired stuff, zip files an all kinds of binary files which shouldn't be in there.

However, I want the source files to run through a code-checker and add the checker-logs to the archive.

The archive soooo big that I gave-up after 30Gbyte of initial checkout. So, I am stuck with an archive that I can't checkout initially.

In order to 'carve-out' the important and not-important files I have come-up with the follow steps:

1. perform a svn list on the archive
2. filter the files that I want (around 200.000 files of source files) in a list.
3. use this list to construct a `.bat` file that does a `svn update --force --parents`
4. perform a `svn checkout --depth empty` (initial working copy)
5. use the command-file from 3).
6. run the code-checkers and cvs add-and-update the files to the archive.
   ( I know that it's best to just build a new repository, but I need to convince the owners of the code to check their code first.)

My question is: at step 3) should I also include the SVN directories like tag/releases/branch as well? Or can I ignore them and still do the `cvs-add-and-update` at step6)?

Thanks in advance, Martijn